# ngbTooltipConfig tooltipClass not loading custom style tooltip

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, ng-bootstrap

I am trying to add custom class to ngbTooltip which is working fine on ng-bootstrap official documentation
[ngBootstrap Link](https://stackblitz.com/run?file=app/tooltip-customclass.ts)

I am trying to replicate the same in my code:

**tooltip-test.component.html**

```
<div class="row mt-5 ml-5">
  <div class="col">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ngbTooltip="Tool tip on top" placement="top"
      tooltipClass="my-custom-class">Tooltip</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**tooltip-test.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbTooltipConfig } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tooltip-test',
  templateUrl: './tooltip-test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tooltip-test.component.css'],
  providers: [NgbTooltipConfig],
  // encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class TooltipTestComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(tooltipConfig: NgbTooltipConfig) {
    tooltipConfig.openDelay = 500;
    tooltipConfig.tooltipClass = 'my-custom-class'
   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**tooltip-test.component.css**

```
.my-custom-class .tooltip-inner {
  background-color: darkgreen;
  font-size: 125%;
}
.my-custom-class .arrow::before {
  border-top-color: darkgreen;
}
```

But I want to achieve same without using `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` or `::ng-deep` or `:host` in my code.
`tooltipConfig.openDelay = 500;` is working fine but 
`tooltipConfig.tooltipClass = 'my-custom-class'` is not loading class.
I even tried `tooltipClass="my-custom-class"` in HTML.
Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

[Stackblitz Link where code is not working](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngbootstrap-tooltip-custom)

Comment: you can't do it without using `::ng-deep`

Comment: @AymenTAGHLISSIA I am not allowed to use it. It's deprecated and messes up css in a lot of ways

Answer (score -1):

All you need is to understand what is view encapsulation in Angular. Here is a good article: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/06/29/shadow-dom-strategies-in-angular2.html